# BasicTextField doesn't delete properly when we use custom decorationBox, in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is my decorationBox argument in BasicTextField. When I delete or press backspace, it sometimes removes two characters and sometimes it removes one by one but doesn't remove the last one. And it works just perfect when I remove decorationBox.

```
decorationBox = {
        Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
            repeat(digitCount) { index ->
                DigitView(
                    index,
                    pinText,
                    digitColor,
                    digitSize,
                    containerSize,
                    type = type,
                    isError
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            }
        }
    }
```

and this in the decorationBox i-e DigitView

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(containerSize)
        .background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
        .border(
            width = 0.5.dp,
            color = if (isError)  ErrorColor else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)
        ),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(
        text = if (index >= pinText.length) "" else pinText[index].toString(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
        style = TypographyM3.bodyMedium.copy(
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        ),
        fontSize = digitSize,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    if (type == PIN_VIEW_TYPE_UNDERLINE) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(digitColor)
                .height(1.dp)
                .width(containerSize)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `decorationBox` has input parameter called `innerTextField`. you must call it exactly once - without it it's not gonna work reliably

Comment: Can you give any example @PhilDukhov

Comment: check out `TextField` source code - input parameter `innerTextField` declared in `decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->`, it's responsible for drawing/handling touches of text input, and should be added to view tree by calling it once.